# Svg to jpg or png file using Paperclip in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I've been using paperclip for a while, allowing my users to upload svg files to it. The problem here is i would like to convert that svg file into a png (or jpg, it doesnt matter). But i dont know if there is a convert_option value to transform it, or if we can do something about it.

When i run 

`convert file.svg file.png`

in my console, i'm getting

`` attribute not recognized: n
attribute not recognized: u
attribute not recognized: n
attribute not recognized: u
convert: unable to open image `#': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert: unable to open image `#': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504. ``

I'm using macosx with imagemagick

Comment: You are probably using the ImageMagick internal MSVG to process SVG files. It is the least functional of the SVG renderers. If you do not have RSVG or Inkscape installed, then try one of those. RSVG is a delegate library that must be installed with IM and would show if you do `convert -version`. Inkscape is the best and simply needs to be on your system where ImageMagick can find it (i.e., in your PATH). Can you post a link to your svg file? If so, I can test on my Mac with IM 6.9.9.25 Q16 using RSVG. I do not have Inkscape installed.

Comment: Hey @fmw42 thank you for your reply. Here you have a link to a svg that i woudl like to conver to png/jpg

http://dev.stackprint.net/system/spree/images/377/original/preview.svg?1511205493

Comment: `@Lucas Juarez` It converts fine for me to either png or jpg with IM 6.9.9.25 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra using RSVG (librsvg @2.40.18_0) installed as a delegate for ImageMagick. `convert -version` shows: Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo fftw fontconfig freetype gslib jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr png ps rsvg tiff webp x xml zlib

Comment: i was able to do it with the librsvg!!! but the problem here is how do i do that in the paperclip configuration? is there a way to use convert_options in the has_attached_file method?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know paperclip. Perhaps it has direct calls to imagemagick or you could use some kind of subprocess to make calls to imagemagick.

Comment: Hey @fmw42 i could implement it using rsvg-convert! thank you so much! i made my own implementation just creating a tmp file before saving it to paperclip.